# Lap Synchonization with different speeds and starting points

Tags: sequences-and-series

4 entities are travelling around a lap of 1280 meters.

The first entity is travelling at 1m/s, the second at 2m/s, the third at 3m/s and the fourth at 4m/s.

The first entity starts at 1m, the second at 2m, the third at 8m and the fourth at 16m.

I am looking to work out how many seconds it will take for them to synchronize (be at the same point of the track at the same time).

I have created a model that will simply brute force it, but I'm searching for a more elegant method that will also scale up to different running speeds and start variables (if such a thing exists).

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to compute?  When they pass each other?  Finishing times?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot the most important part of the question.

I am trying to work out how many seconds it will take for them to synchronize (be at the same point of the track at the same time). Essentially when they will pass each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The times when the first two horses meet are times when $1+t \equiv 2+2t \pmod {1280}$  This is easy to see-it happens when the second horse has gained $1279$ on the first plus some multiple of $1280$, so happens at $1279+1280k$ for some integral $k$  Similarly, the third must gain $1273$ at a speed of $2$, so will pass the first at $636.5+640m$.  You can continue like this for each pair.  As the speed differences are integral, the passing times will repeat after the fourth horse has gained three laps on the first.  If you need all of them to meet, you can check the list of meeting times for a coincidence.